# Creating Swift Array from coredata

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

My entity in coredata is like this
value1,value2,value3,value4

I am trying to display graph which takes as array like this

```
AASeriesElement()
                    .name("Range Chart")
                    .type(.columnrange)
                    .data([
                        [120, 80],
                        [130, 95],
                        [135, 100],
                        [125, 95]
                        ])
                    .toDic()!, 
                AASeriesElement()
                    .name("Line Chart")
                    .data([72, 80, 90, 72, 80])
                    .toDic()!
```

Where data for range chart is 
[[Value1,Value2],[Value1,Value2],[Value1,Value2]] so on//each row and 
data from line chart is [row1val3,row2val3,row3val3] and so on.

I am bit new to swift so confused how can i do it?

Current I am getting coredata rows as follows (in view load as function call)

```
let managedObjectContext=self.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ItemName")

        // Add Sort Descriptor
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        do {
            myItems = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Item]
            print( myItems.count)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to retrieve record")
            print(error)
        }
```

Need to create those array out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use map to convert your entity properties to an array

```
let data = myItems.map { [$0.value1, $0.value2] }
```